# Parallel search through elasticsearch perform very slow (more than 5 runs at the same time)

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

NEST/Elasticsearch.Net version: 5.6

Elasticsearch version: 5.5

Description of the problem including expected versus actual behavior:

I have an .NET back end which launch 8 search queries through elasticsearch. Each search takes roughly within a seconds, but the whole waiting time is around 2 mins, which is super weird. Is there any setting I could optimize the parallel performance? Or how do i know what happened during these long 2 mins?

I also cap the timeline here, and also the tookMillisecond is the Took in the elasticsearch response.

Thank you very much.

[image]

.NET Code will be something like:

```
public static async Task<Dictionary<ESSearchLevel, List<ESResultEntityBase>>> SearchCallers(DateTime from, DateTime to, int minSeconds)
        {
            minSeconds = minSeconds <= 0 ? 1 : minSeconds;
            var url = ESConfig.restEndPoint;
            var index = ESConfig.indexCallsStart + ESConfig.indexSuffix;
            var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri(url));
            settings.DefaultIndex(index);
            var eClient = new ElasticClient(settings);

            Func<QueryContainerDescriptor<ESConferenceCall>, QueryContainer> query =
                q =>
                q.Term(p => p.type, "conferenceCall")
                && q.Term(p => p.conference.isWaitingAreaCall, true)
                && q.Term(p => p.conferenceCall.role, "caller")
                && q.Range(d => d.Field(f => f.conference.lengthSeconds).GreaterThanOrEquals(minSeconds))
                && q.DateRange(qd => qd.Field(f => f.timestamp).GreaterThanOrEquals(from.ToUniversalTime().ToString(ESConfig.ElasticSearchTimeFormat)))
                && q.DateRange(qd => qd.Field(f => f.timestamp).LessThanOrEquals(to.ToUniversalTime().ToString(ESConfig.ElasticSearchTimeFormat)));
            Func<AggregationContainerDescriptor<ESConferenceCall>, IAggregationContainer> aggFunc =
                a =>
                a.Terms("caller", t => t
                    .Field(p => p.call.personId)
                    .Size(ESConfig.SearchMaxConsultationOrCaller)
                    .Aggregations(a2 => a2
                        .Sum("sum-call", d2 => d2.Field(f => f.call.lengthSeconds))
                        .Sum("sum-conference", d2 => d2.Field(f => f.conference.lengthSeconds))))
                ));

            var resultTask = eClient.SearchAsync<ESConferenceCall>(
                s => s
                .Query(query)
                .Size(0)
                .Aggregations(aggFunc)
                 );
            QueryTimer.Records.Add(new QueryTimer("start ES SearchCallers"));

            var result = await resultTask;
            QueryTimer.Records.Add(new QueryTimer("finish ES SearchCallers", result.Took));

            if (!result.IsValid)
            {
                throw new Exception(result.DebugInformation, result.OriginalException);
            }

            if (result.Aggregations.Count == 0)
            {
                return null; // no result
            }

            var callers = result.Aggregations["caller"] as BucketAggregate;

            var dic = new Dictionary<ESSearchLevel, List<ESResultEntityBase>>();

            var callerList = new List<ESResultEntityBase>();
            foreach (KeyedBucket<object> item in callers.Items)
            {
                ESResultEntityBase en = new ESResultEntityBase()
                {
                    Id = int.Parse(item.Key.ToString()),
                    Count = Convert.ToInt32(item.DocCount.Value)
                };
                en.Values[ESAggKey.SumOfLengthSeconds] = Math.Min(
                        (item.Aggregations["sum-call"] as ValueAggregate).Value.Value,
                        (item.Aggregations["sum-conference"] as ValueAggregate).Value.Value);
                callerList.Add(en);
            }


            dic[ESSearchLevel.Caller] = callerList;

            return dic;
        }
```

Comment: Can you post the query or the codes that you make the call ?

Comment: Are you instantiating a new `ConnectionSettings` and `ElasticClient` on each method call? Consider using single instances and sharing as they are thread-safe and make heavy use of caching

Comment: Yes each async search call init a new connection setting and new elasticclient. I will make them share single elasticclient see what is going on. Will let u know what will happen.

Comment: @RussCam the result is also interesting. After sharing same client instance. Looks like the top 6 query run first, and they all finish within 10 sec. then the last query finish after a min later, but its TOOK only shows 1.4 second. Is there a parallel limit setting in elasticclient?

Comment: The client puts a limit on the number of concurrent connections, but TCP connections will be reused. It's worth running the connection through a proxy such as Fiddler https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/logging-with-fiddler.html to better understand total request time. `took` only includes time taken for Elasticsearch to _process_ the query. I suspect time is being taken up elsewhere in this case

Comment: @RussCam hi I think your single instance helped my case. When I said slow, it is my local host when I test in it.  However once I deployed to the server, it runs fast, and looks like all queries run parallel on the server. I will put single client for the whole site, which will server all request. Thank you very much.

Comment: No problem, glad you got to the bottom of it

Comment: Yes. I will take yours as the answer.